# Backbone, requirejs, multiple views, one collection

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

Below you can see four basic requireJS files. How can I have multiple Backbone.js views that will all share one collection which has been initiated and fetched elsewhere?

*Please note*

I am aware I can pass the collection in ***App.js*** however I would like to refrain from doing so since I will probably have many collections that will need to be used in many views, and I don't want to pass each of them in ***App.js***.

**Collection.js**

```
return Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '...'
});
```

**App.js**

```
var collection = new Collection();

$.when(collection.fetch()).done(function(){
    new View1();
    new View2();
});
```

**View1.js**

```
define(['Collection'], function(Collection){
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            console.log('Need the initiated, fetched collection here...');
        });
    });
});
```

**View2.js**

```
define(['Collection'], function(Collection){
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            console.log('Need the initiated, fetched collection here...');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: RequireJS runs function body code once and the `return` statement alone multiple times. You can, hence, create a **Collection Instance** and return that to every person who requires it.

**Collection.js**

```
var CollectionConstructor = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '...'
});
var CollectionInstance = new CollectionConstructor();
return CollectionInstance;
```

---

Alternatively, if you want more than one instance of CollectionInstance running around, and don't want to pass it to the views, I don't believe anything short of global variables will help. That would look like:

**Globals.js**

```
var AppGlobals = AppGlobals || {};
AppGlobals.oneSet = new Collection ();
AppGlobals.anotherSet = new Collection ();
```

You can now have your views depend on Globals.js and access them from here. Depending on your use, either of these two should work. Keep in mind that in the second approach, your Collection.js is unmodified.